# Trying to connect laravel to localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create tables within my database the database I created through laravel schema but they are not appearing in PhpMyAdmin. I have phpMyAdmin set up in my sites on my home directory. I access php using localhost/~myunsername/phpmyadmin.

I'm connecting to the database in Laravel's app/config/database.php

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'firstapp',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',

        ),
```

I'm creating the tables in routes.php using schema

```
Route::get('/', function()
{

  Schema::create('art2', function($newtable)
  {
    $newtable->increments('id');
    $newtable->string('artist');
    $newtable->string('title',500);
    $newtable->text('description');
    $newtable->date('created');
    $newtable->boolean('alumni');
    $newtable->timestamps();
  }); 

    return View::make('hello');
});
```

When I try to run this again I get this error..

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'art2' already exists (SQL: create table `art2`

Which is saying I've already created those tables but they aren't showing up in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Have you double checked that the user logging into mysql in phpmyadmin has permissions to view the db and tables?

Comment: Yeah I can log in and view as well as create no problem!

Comment: I think it might have something to do with my 'host' settings when connecting to the database. I tried changing it to 127.0.0.1 but no luck. MyPhpAdmin is located within the apache sites folder on my laptop and is running from there.

Comment: When you connect to phpMyAdmin, the right side of the main page has some connection information. Under the "Database server" area what are show for "Server" and "User"?